# How to solve/approach for counting the large range of numbers in mind for this particular type of eliminating numbers?

Tags: combinatorics

Here is the following question. I was wondering on how to solve such questions.

100 people standing in a circle in an order 1 to 100. No 1 has a sword. He kills next person i.e. No 2 and gives sword to next to next i.e No 3. All person does the same until only 1 survives. Which number survives at the last?

---- I couldn't solve this. This was my approach.

1. I made the small model of it. Rather than solving till 100, I made a series until 10 only. I thought whatever the answer will be from 1 to 10, the same answer will apply for 1 to 100. The 100 is just an illusion. I was wrong the answer is greater than 10.
2. I thought of literally counting until I am left with one person. I just gave up, my brain got tired after doing a few iterations.

My question is how to tackle such kind of questions. What I should do ideally or think ideally? Please help me here.

Comment: It would be easy to answer if the number of people was a power of $2$ (e.g., $128$).

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with writing all the numbers from 1 to 100 and just eliminating them one after another? This took me 5 minutes and if I made no mistake the solution is <strike>83</strike> 73.

I don't see an analytical way to solve this problem, because the sequence of people that get eliminated follows a rather complicated pattern. More specifically, a problem occurs everytime your sequence "crosses" the beginning of the circle from person 100 to person 1. But this type of problem can easily be processed with the help of a computer. Writing a program to solve this problem shouldn't be too complicated.

**Edit:** Here's a program in C++(11):

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>

constexpr int num = 100;

int next(int& value){
    value = (value + 1)%num;
    return value;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    std::vector<bool> elim(num, false);
    int position = 0;   // Person that has the sword
    for(int i = 1 ; i < num ; ++i){
        do{ // find the first person alive
            next(position);
        }while(elim[position]);
        elim[position] = true;  // Eliminate person
        do{ // find the next person alive
            next(position);
        }while(elim[position]);
    }
    for(int i = 0 ; i < num ; ++i){
        if(!elim[i])
            printf("Last person alive is #%i\n", i + 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a result of a simulation. The first rounds are easy to understand. In the first all even numbers are eliminated, in the second all numbers $n \pmod 4 \equiv 3, $ etc

Round 1, difference 2, eliminated:
2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,26,28,30,32,34,36,38,40,42,44,46,48,50,52,54,56,58,60,62,64,66,68,70,72,74,76,78,80,82,84,86,88,90,92,94,96,98,100

Round 2, difference 4, eliminated:
3,7,11,15,19,23,27,31,35,39,43,47,51,55,59,63,67,71,75,79,83,87,91,95,99

Round 3, difference 8, eliminated:
5,13,21,29,37,45,53,61,69,77,85,93

Round 4, difference 16, eliminated:
1,17,33,49,65,81,97

Round 5, difference 32, eliminated:
25,57,89

Round 6, difference 64, eliminated:
41,9

**Survivor: 73**